# Can you add html markup in Kendo UI Tabstrip tab text during binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Trying to add a "x" in my tabs similar to the "x" in the Chrome browser tabs, to be able to click on to remove the tab. Just double checking, but it seems you can't add html markup to your tabs (not the content, but the tabs themselves), using the MVC wrappers in the BindTo method like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
.Name("OrderDetailsTabs")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class="orderDtlTabs"})
.BindTo(Model, (tab, tabModel) =>
    {
        tab.Text = "<a class='k-link'><span>Part: " + tabModel.WOHdr.OrderDetailId + 
                    "<button onclick='return deleteWorkOrder(" + tabModel.WOHdr.Id +")' class='delete k-button' title='Delete Work Order'></button>" +
                    "</span></a>"; // tab text
```

I know I can do some DOM manipulation after the tabs load, but just seeing if I'm missing something to do it at binding time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up doing post binding DOMnastics to update the html in the tabs after they load:

```
function addDeleteIconToTabs() {    
    var $tabItems = $('ul.k-tabstrip-items > li.k-item');
    $tabItems.each(function (index, tabLI) {
        var strTabId = $(tabLI).attr('aria-controls');
        var $tabContainerDiv = $('#' + strTabId);
        var intWorkOrderId = $tabContainerDiv.find('input.wohid').val();
        var strButtonHtml = "<button onclick='return deleteWorkOrder(this," + intWorkOrderId + ")' class='delete k-button' title='Delete Work Order'></button>";
        $(tabLI).append(strButtonHtml);
    });
}
```